# Redis - Lua tables as return values - why is this not working

Tags: lua, redis, lua-table

When I run this code through redis EVAL it return no results.  Any idea why this is not working?

```
redis-cli EVAL "$(cat bug.lua)" 0
```

#### bug.lua

```
local retv = {}
retv["test"] = 1000

return retv
```

If I initialize the table that value alone gets printed.

```
$ cat bug.lua 
--!/usr/bin/env lua


local retv = {"This", "is", "a", "bug" }
retv["test"] = 1000

return retv

$ redis-cli EVAL "$(cat bug.lua)" 2 a b
1) "This"
2) "is"
3) "a"
4) "bug"
```

Comment: does your actual command have a closing quote before the 0? wont' work without it, wondering if typo or real

Comment: Yes you are right.  It is just a typo here.  I have it right on the command line.  Fixing the question.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: does it work if bug.lua has `local msg = "hi"; return msg`? do you get an error message if you cat a file that does not exist? You are returning a reference to the table, not a string representation of the table, does Redis know how to display the reference (a pointer, essentially)?

Comment: Lua interpreter works fine and loads the file fine as well.  Have checked both.

Comment: As far as the return of a table reference, Redis manual (http://redis.io/commands/eval) says that a Lua table is converted to an appropriate redis datastructure.  So I am not sure if there is a problem there.

Comment: Interestingly.  I made a small change to initialize the table and that works fine.  Have updated the question with the changed script.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you refer to the [Redis `EVAL` documentation](http://redis.io/commands/eval) you can see what are the rules Redis uses to convert a Lua table into a Redis reply:

1. Lua table (array) -> Redis multi bulk reply (**truncated to the first
   nil inside the Lua array if any**)
2. Lua table with a single ok field -> Redis status reply
3. Lua table with a single err field -> Redis error reply

So except with special cases 2 and 3, Redis assumes your table is a sequence (i.e list) which means it reads `retv[1], retv[2], ...` until it encounters a `nil` element (here is the corresponding [source code section](https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/f16ad11/src/scripting.c#L804-L819)).

This explains why `retv["test"]` is ignored in your case.

If you change your code with:

```
local retv = {"This", "is", "a", "bug" }
retv[5] = 1000
return retv
```

Then this additional element gets returned:

```
1) "This"
2) "is"
3) "a"
4) "bug"
5) (integer) 1000
```

Comment: That was it.  Redis does not support arbitrary tables of Lua.  Didnt know that!  Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes! This is because it needs to convert the Lua returned value into a valid [Redis protocol](http://redis.io/topics/protocol) (a.k.a RESP) data type, namely Simple Strings, Errors, Integers, Bulk Strings and Arrays - and there is no associative array.

Comment: Thank you very much. This helps me a lot! Also deltheil wrote important sentence "...is no associative array", this helps me figure out whats wrong!

Answer (score 11):

Answer from @deltheil is valid.

Remember though that you can use cjson library to pack tables and pass them to consumers.

Your lua file:

```
local retv = {"This", "is", "a", "bug" }
retv["test"] = 1000

return cjson.encode(retv)
```

Command:

```
redis-cli EVAL "$(cat bug.lua)" 0
```

Result:

```
"{\"1\":\"This\",\"2\":\"is\",\"3\":\"a\",\"4\":\"bug\",\"test\":1000}"
```