# How to use redis.call("mget") using lua

Tags: redis, lua, lua-table

I have following scnario using lua with redis script

```
local valuesForMset = {"key_1", "0", "key_2", "0"};
redis.call("MSET", unpack(valuesForMset))
```

I would expect MGET key_1 to return 0 but instead it returns `nil` . I have already tried following as well

```
local valuesForMset = {"key_1", "key_2"};
redis.call("MSET", unpack(valuesForMset))
```

And result is same. Has anyone used lua for MSET? If yes how did you achieve setting key-value with MSET.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have not created a table with values, you have created the Lua equivalent of a set in this line

```
local valuesForMset = {"key_1", "0", "key_2", "0"};
```

To be a Lua table with key-value pairs it should be

```
local valuesForMset = {}
valuesForMset["key_1"] = 0
valuesForMset["key_2"] = 0
```

Your original code created a table with four keys all with the `nil` value.

Comment: For lua script that is executed at redis it is not possible to do local `valuesForMset = {}
valuesForMset["key_1"] = 0
valuesForMset["key_2"] = 0` . This has been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298763/redis-lua-tables-as-return-values-why-is-this-not-working . Thank you for  taking time to answer.

Comment: @barnstola - Use the appropriate syntax within Redis, then, however my answer stands.